# How to add a .jar to Android Chromium/Chrome build

Tags: java, build, jar, chromium, gn

I have the Chromium/Chrome browser source code from the Google git repository on my Linux machine. I can build an APK and install it onto my device successfully. My Question is: How do I include a prebuilt .jar to be included into the APK build? I'm trying to include org.xbill.dns_2.1.7.jar into the APK.

I've tried creating a subdirectory in the /chromium/src/third_party/android_deps/libs/ and placing the .jar in it. But when I build the project it isn't included. . .

In simple steps what do I need to do?

Comment: Chromium uses GN build system. Look up GN build system on Google

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. Here is what I have that doesn't work:
In file chrome/android/BUILD.gn section for `"android_resources("chrome_app_java_resources") {"` I've added this line to the deps:
`"//third_party/android_deps:org_xbill_dns_java",`

Then in file third_party/android_deps/BUILD.gn file I added:
`java_prebuilt("org_xbill_dns_java") {
  jar_path = "libs/org_xbill_dns/org.xbill.dns_2.1.7.jar"
  output_name = "org_xbill_dns_java"
  supports_android = true
}`

This builds fine but it does not include the .jar in the compiled APK.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I've made some progress with this unsolved problem. In my above explaining I had wrongly added the reference to `"chrome_app_java_resources"` where it **SHOULD** be to `chrome_java` build instead.  
  
So now I get a build-error of:  
_Error: Compilation can't be completed because the class `sun.net.spi.nameservice.NameServiceDescriptor` is missing._  
  
Any ideas on how to fix this one?